# While Loops and Reverse Fibonacci

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I've come across a problem. I'm trying to make a class which takes the maximum number that a user puts in and adds the integer before it until it gets to 0, however, when I run it, the numbers get larger and larger until it crashes. What seems to be throwing this into an infinite loop?

```
public class Summation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EasyReader console = new EasyReader();
        System.out.print("Debug? (Y/N): ");
        char debug = console.readChar();    
        if ((debug!='Y')&&(debug!='N')){
            System.out.println("Please enter Y or N");
            main(null); 
        }
        else{

            System.out.print("Enter max range:");
            int max = console.readInt();
            int s = sum(max,debug);     
            System.out.print(s);
        }
    }
    public static int sum(int m, char d){
        int sm = 1;
        boolean isRunning = true;
        while ((isRunning == true)&&(d=='Y')){
            if ((--m)==0) {
                isRunning = false;
                }
            else{
                sm = m+(--m);
                System.out.println("sm is"+sm);
                }
        while ((isRunning == true)&&(d=='N')){
            if ((--m)==0) {
                isRunning = false;
                }
            else{
                sm = m+(--m);
                }           
            }
        }return sm;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you **add two positive integers** to each other and are **surprised that the result is larger** than the numbers? Did you really think this through? This has nothing to do with programming, your code is flawless: it does exactly as specified. This is PEBKAC.

Comment: @ppeterka66 One of the integers is supposed to count down until it reaches 0, and the process should terminate at that point.

Comment: Minor note, don't use `isRunning == true` in your conditions, `isRunning` is enough and it prevents you from making mistake of assigning boolean value to variable like `isRunning = true`.

Comment: @Showman - then the problem is that this is not anywhere connected to Fibonacci... This is just a sum of all the numbers between 1 and max, which is I remember correctly is solvable by `n*(n+1)/2`, n being the max number - which does not need a single loop. And the error is likely that the evaluation of the if statements decrement m, while the else statements decrement it again...

Comment: It terminates fine for me with input of 'Y' and 501.  What input are you giving it?  Also, what is the purpose of the nested `while`?  The outermost `while` will only be entered if d=='Y', so the nested loop will never do anything.

Comment: @Tap try with an input that is even, like 500

Comment: In that case, why not use a condition like `if ((--m) <= 0)`?

Comment: Revise your line sm = m+(--m);

Answer (score 0):

There's a scenario where your condition for exit

```
if ((--m)==0)
```

will never again be reached, because `m` is already less than 0, and it's never going back.

that scenario is whenever `m` is an even number.

```
while ((isRunning == true)&&(d=='Y'))
{
    // this condition decriments `m` every time it runs, regardless of whether it evaluates to true
    if ((--m)==0) 
    {
        // if `m` was set to 0 on your last iteration, it will be set to -1
        isRunning = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // if m is 1 before this line it will be 0 after it.
        sm = m+(--m);
        System.out.println("sm is"+sm);
    }
    while ((isRunning == true)&&(d=='N'))
    {
        // this code will never get executed       
    }
}
return sm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your problem is very simple
Just modify the condition

```
if (m==0) {
    isRunning = false;
}
```

When you are checking `--m == 0`, it is very much possible that m will be jumping over 0 and will enter negative territory without even setting this condition to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing is wrong :).

First - FORMATTING. You maybe even dont know that, but the second while is INSIDE the first while cycle. If you use netbeans, its ALT+SHIFT+F.

The using of --m is not good for your example, cause it firsts decrease the "m" value and then it compares. So even when you asking at

```
(--m)==0
```

you decrease a value. And because you are using it again at

```
sm = m+(--m)
```

you can even skip the "0" value and get into negative numbers.

However if you want only "add numbers in reverse order from given number to 0 in while loop" it is not fibonacci and you can use this code (it could be done better, but this is using your code) :

```
public class Summation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(10, 'Y'));
    }

    public static int sum(int m, char d) {
        int sm = 0;
        boolean isRunning = true;
        while ((isRunning == true) && (d == 'Y')) {
            sm += m;
            if (m == 0) {
                isRunning = false;
            } else {
                m--;
                System.out.println("sm is" + sm);
            }
            while ((isRunning == true) && (d == 'N')) {
                if ((--m) == 0) {
                    isRunning = false;
                } else {
                    sm = m + (--m);
                }
            }
        }
        return sm;
    }
}
```

Note that second while cycle couldnt be reached - it passes only when "d == Y" and then it starts only when "d == N"